# How to configure Proxychains in backtrack?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to configure proxychains.conf file but when i run any application from proxychains like firefox, it can't open the webpage and also terminal is showing "need more proxies !" ??

I have tried all three types of setting in conf. file ????

Please help me to rectify this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the BT forums: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=1496

Comment: yes...   i have gone through it but the result is same....

Answer (score 2):

To use proxychains correctly you need to populate your proxychains.conf file with valid proxies. The reason your are getting the response "need more proxies" is because either there are either no proxies in your proxychains.conf file or the ones that you have entered are no longer available.

The default entry at the bottom of the file (socks 127.0.0.1 9050) is for the TOR proxy service, which is probably the best option for most. Tor is a public proxy service, in case you didn't know, that offers a small measure of online anonymity. For you to use proxychains with tor you have to remove the shebang (#) from the tor entry, and then make sure the to daemon is running

`service tor start` 
or 
`/etc/init.d/tor start`.

If you want to use proxychains with Firefox then let me just say don't. Proxychains and Firefox (or any other browser for that matter) don't play well together. I've tried many ways to proxify my web browsing with proxychains and it just won't work. Even with the proxy_dns on or off (see proxychains.conf file) the browser refuses to connect. The best method I've found for to proxy my browser activities is by using a **pac** file as your proxy autoconfig file. I use [proxynova's pac file](http://www.proxynova.com/proxy.pac) with a good amount of success. You can use TOR with firefox but you will find (via cmyip.com or other public IP lookup service) that your public IP will still show up (unproxied).

If you would like to use more than one proxy or just want to stay away from tor altogether (can you say big brother?) then you will have to hunt down your own proxy servers. There are many websites now that offer valid proxies with various levels of anonymity. I've actually written a python script that will populate your proxychains.conf file for you with a minimum of 30 valid proxies. The link is here [proxyupdate](https://github.com/xajnx/proxyupdate.git). It will retrieve more than 30 proxies but you will have to edit the script(instructions in the README).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you tried all three types of setting in conf file?

To make things straight, this is what worked for me to make proxychains work without any problem:

- By default, proxychains use port 9050. That means that it uses TOR to pass traffic through it. So first of all you have to install TOR. After installing tor (apt-get install TOR), you have to start it by using the command "service tor start" or if you wanna have a debugging mode just type "TOR". If you wanna use another proxy, then change the ip and the port depending on your needs.
- The second thing you have to do, is to edit proxychains conf. Open "/etc/proxychains.conf" with an editor and go to the end of file. Comment out socks4 line and put a new line refering to socks5 like that:

  ```
  #socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
   socks5 127.0.0.1 9050
  ```
- Save the file and type again "proxychains firefox". Trying to access a webpage will cause some retrasmissions which you will be able to see in yout terminal window.

Comment: I did this, however, even if tor is running, and it works, I always get `Dynamic chain ... 127.0.0.1:9050  ...timeout` and below `!!! you need more proxies !!!`

Answer (score 0):

I meet a big bug for that should use
`socks5` rather than `SOCKS5`, please note not use Caps